# Redis reply all queries with 'QUEUED'

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

After a while running my app Redis didn't answer queries and only say QUEUED.
It seems a transaction is open, while I execute all transactions in my code.
Why is the transaction not finished? Is there a way to detect and rollback it?

I've taken a look at transaction object, there is no discard, rollback or something similar.

I have this log when the problem started.

```
   StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: An unknown error occurred when 
   writing the message
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message 
   message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server)
   at StackExchange.Redis.RedisTransaction.Execute(CommandFlags flags)
```

while Redis keep replying 'QUEUED', the monitor command just logged PING.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your transaction is not ended properly. For example [`EXEC`](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) command is not executed for the begin command [`MULTY`](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) in the same redis connection.

Here is an example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> MULTI                                                                                               
OK                                                                                                                      
127.0.0.1:6379> set x 123                                                                                            
QUEUED                                                                                                                                  
127.0.0.1:6379> set y 456                                                                                               
QUEUED                                                                                                                  
127.0.0.1:6379> set z 678                                                                                               
QUEUED                                                                                                                  
127.0.0.1:6379> exec                                                                                                    
1) OK                                                                                                                   
2) OK                                                                                                                   
3) OK
```

no matter how many you have inputted after command **`MULTY`** it will always show **QUEUED** until **`EXEC`** command is executed. Check your code carefully if

> any thing missed after transaction started

OR You are using same shared redis-connection object to store values.

**UPDATE:** from comment:
Roll back is not possible in redis, but discard this transaction by :

```
> SET foo 1
OK
> MULTI
OK
> INCR foo
QUEUED
> DISCARD
OK
```

> But the thing that I'm really looking for is that is there a way to detect and rollback it?

Yes, it is possible to detect errors. But roll back is not natively supported by redis. from the redis docs:

> [**Why Redis does not support roll backs?**](https://redis.io/topics/transactions#why-redis-does-not-support-roll-backs)
>
> If you have a relational databases background, the fact that Redis commands can fail during a transaction, but still Redis will execute the rest of the transaction instead of rolling back, may look odd to you.
>
> However there are good opinions for this behavior:
>
> Redis commands can fail only if called with a wrong syntax (and the problem is not detectable during the command queueing), or against keys holding the wrong data type: this means that in practical terms a failing command is the result of a programming errors, and a kind of error that is very likely to be detected during development, and not in production.
>   Redis is internally simplified and faster because it does not need the ability to roll back.
>   An argument against Redis point of view is that bugs happen, however it should be noted that in general the roll back does not save you from programming errors. For instance if a query increments a key by 2 instead of 1, or increments the wrong key, there is no way for a rollback mechanism to help. Given that no one can save the programmer from his or her errors, and that the kind of errors required for a Redis command to fail are unlikely to enter in production, we selected the simpler and faster approach of not supporting roll backs on errors.

Comment: Thank you Ruhul for your answer. But the thing that I'm really looking for is that is there a way to detect and rollback it? In my case, an unknown exception has occurred, but how can I roll back it? Or simply I should try to execute it again?